# How React-hook-form interacting with each another fields?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

So I am basically new with-react-hook-form I have created a form with controlled inputs, where my conditions for 2nd input is based on my first input.
My 1st input is duration where I have 2 options 'Monthly' and 'Yearly'.
My 2nd input is Budget where the minimum budget is 200 for Monthly and 400 for Yearly.

This is my code:

```
<div style={{ marginTop: theme.spacing(1) }}>
    <Controller
      as={Select}
      row
      name="duration"
      control={control}
      defaultValue="Monthly"
      fullWidth
      label={<FormattedMessage {...messages.duration} />}
      margin="normal"
      options={DURATION_OPTIONS}
      rules={{
        required: 'Required'
      }}
    />
  </div>


  <div>
    <Controller
      as={NumberField}
      row
      name="budget"
      control={control}
      defaultValue="1000"
      fullWidth
      label={<FormattedMessage {...messages.howMuchBudget} />}
      margin="normal"
      rules={{
        required: true,
        min: {
          value: 400,
          message: 'Min is 400',
        }
      }}
    />
  </div>
```

Now I want to trigger my 2nd field validation based on my 1st field validation dynamically. if my duration is Monthly selected then the min validation for 2nd input should be 200 and if my duration is selected as Yearly then min validation for 2nd input should be 400.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `getValues` to fetch the values of the form, then access the ones you want inside your validation: https://react-hook-form.com/api/#getValues

Comment: I tried this but not working for me can you provide the just rules props with getValues() ?

Comment: Hey @Jayce444 need some code for it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a basic example. In this case, the last name has to be shorter than the first name, otherwise you'll get an error.

```
function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors, getValues } = useForm({mode:'onChange'});

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label>First name</label>
      <input name="firstName" defaultValue='Potato' ref={register} />

      <label>Last name (must be shorter than first name)</label>
      <input name="lastName" ref={register({
        validate: {
          shorterThanFirstName: value => value.length < getValues().firstName?.length,
        }
      })} />
      {errors.lastName && <p>Last name must be shorter than first name</p>}

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: The validation won't be triggered here in case if the user wrote a last name and then a shorter first name